# How to convert image to dataurl

Tags: jquery, html

Friends I downloaded one plugin for image cropper, that working fine, but after croped the image I want store the data base but I dont know how find the cropped image values,

While I am checking that time I getting like this value

```
console.log(result.toDataURL());
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAFoCAYAAADHMkpRAAAgAElEQ…U9ngkdrDf9mQPIlgpI42z0moo8JpqCjAu8r4RBPCO+/X8BzNNeB1h7SyYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

downloaded link   http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/
 Now I dont know what will do for that solution

Answer (score 0):

You can see in that [plugin](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) they have given the details to crop using PHP. On the bottom of the page you will get the [example](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar). You have to just post the value of input type file and the cropping details like height,width,x,y...etc and you have to crop this using [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php),[Imagemagic](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) etc. Follow the plugin you will get everything you need. Its very easy to integrate.

Comment: From which line number i am getting result,i dont know friend

Comment: I want to insert the database,for that value

Comment: you have to post the image file like regular you do with the height,width... and other details. And then you have to crop the image using PHP.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008911/cropping-image-in-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929759/crop-an-image-after-resizing-in-gd-library

Comment: did you check the PHP example? You are using PHP in backend right?

Comment: Ya i am checking that exaples,from that file which file which line number i have to modified for insert the database

Comment: You did not check that example. You don't have to change any thing. They have done a complete example.